# Kubernetes pods cannot be reached from host but can be reached from node

Tags: kubernetes

It's been some days since I have started to learn Kubernetes. I am a noob in this and don't have any troubleshooting skills or any experience this is my first lab and however I am stuck in my first lab. Now the problem is this I have a VMware workstation where I have hosted my centos box in that box I have installed docker minikube kubectl KVM and then started the lab.

There are two object files which will be shown below ...

```
vi client-pod.yml

apiVersion: v1 
kind: Pod 
metadata:
  name: client-pod
  labels: 
    components: web

spec:
  containers:
    - name: client 
      image: stephengrider/multi-client 
      ports:
        - containerPort: 3000

vi client-pod.service 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service 

metadata:
  name: client-node-port

spec: 
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 3050
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 31515
  selector: 
    component: web
```

after this I use the

```
minikube start --driver=kvm
```

Then after loading it starts

Then I use these commands

```
kubectl apply -f client-pod.yml
kubectl apply -f client-pod.service
```

So after this I use the

```
minikube ip
```

I get a IP:192.168.39.107

Then in browser of host when I use http://192.168.39.107:31515
It shows request not completed or something like that

Can anyone tell me whats going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Pod` labels and `Service` selector aren't same.

Either use `components: web` or `component: web` in both pod and service.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Pod 
metadata:
  name: client-pod
  labels: 
    component: web    # updated labels key
...
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service 

metadata:
  name: client-node-port

spec: 
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 3050
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 31515
  selector: 
    component: web    # it should be same as pod labels
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Ohh that was it.

Thank you for the solution and sorry for the silly mistake

Comment: Hy,
I am stucked in another issue hope you might be able to help me 
After the setup I turned off my VM from the host machine today 
I reopened the VM and started the work

Entered command:


"Minikube start --driver=kvm"
Then I DID

Minikube ssh 

After I get ssh connection when I try to ping 

ping google.com   ===============>> It gives result as
PING google.com (142.250.196.78): 56 data bytes


When I try to ping =======
ping 8.8.8.8 ========== It is unrechable so basically the node cannot connect to the outside world can you help me in this